# Move items up and down

Tags: java, gwt

i want after the button click to move the selected item on the list up or down, i use gwt, and that's what i have done before:

```
  @UiHandler("Up")
    void UpClick(ClickEvent e) {
   ListBox item;
        int i=item.getSelectedIndex();
            if(i>0){
                // add duplicated item in the list
                item.addItem(item.getItemText(i),String.valueOf(i-1));
                // make it the current item
                i=i-2;
                // delete the old occurence of this item
                item.removeItem(i+2);
            }
        }



   @UiHandler("Down")
    void DownClick(ClickEvent e) {
        int i=item.getSelectedIndex();
            if((i!=-1) && (i<item.getItemCount()-1)) {
                item.addItem(item.getItemText(i),String.valueOf(i+1));
                i=i+2;
                item.removeItem(i-2);
            }
        }
```

after i select item and click "up" button, i become the selected item moved down, and not moved up (change with position with the item wich is before the selected item)
before:

```
item1
item2
**item3** 
item4
```

after selecting item3 i want it will be on the item2 position and item2 goes down (position change)

like:

```
item1
**item3**
item2
item4
```

with "down" button is the same, the selected item goes to the end of the list, and not just change the position down with the item that is after the selected item.

Can anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused about that the method `addItem(String, String)` does.

From the [documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ListBox.html) (Emphasis mine): Adds an item to the list box, specifying an **initial value** for the item.

As you can see, the second argument does **not** specify the index at which to add the item. However, the `insertItem(String, int)` method *does* specify an index. You will probably want to use that:

```
@UiHandler("Up")
void UpClick(ClickEvent e) {
    ListBox item;
    int i=item.getSelectedIndex();
    if(i>0){
        // add duplicated item in the list
        item.insertItem(item.getItemText(i),i-1);

        // delete the old occurence of this item
        item.removeItem(i+1);
    }
}


@UiHandler("Down")
void DownClick(ClickEvent e) {
    int i=item.getSelectedIndex();
    if((i!=-1) && (i<item.getItemCount()-1)) {
        item.insertItem(item.getItemText(i),i+2);

        item.removeItem(i);
    }
}
```

I have also taken the liberty of fixing your index math.